# Property of expectation

Tags: statistics, expectation

Give X is a random variable , u(X) is a function of X and c is a constant,

is it true that $E(c[u(X)]) = c[E(u(X))]$

If is it true, can someone provide me with a short proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with: "$\mathbb EcY=c\mathbb EY$ for random variable $Y$ if $\mathbb EY$ exists?" Note that $Y:=u(X)$ is - at least if $u$ is a measurable function, which is to be expected in this context - also a random variable.

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the discrete case:$$E(c[u(X)])=\sum_{i=1}^ncu(x_i) \mathbb P(X=x_i)=c\sum_{i=1}^nu(x_i) \mathbb P(X=x_i)=cE([u(X)]).$$
The proof for the continuous case is the same but with an integral.